# String list remove

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach, contains

I have this code:

```
List<string> lineList = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in theFinalList)
{
    if (line.PartDescription != "")
        lineList.Add(line.PartDescription + " " + line.PartNumber + "\n");
    else
        lineList.Add("N/A " + line.PartNumber + "\n");

    //
    //This is what I am trying to fix:
    if (lineList.Contains("FID") || lineList.Contains("EXCLUDE"))
        // REMOVE THE item in the lineList
}
```

I am trying to go through `theFinalList` in a foreach loop and add each line to a new list called `lineList`.
Once added, I want to remove any entries from that list that contain the text ***"FID"*** or ***"EXCLUDE"***.

I am having trouble removing the entry, can someone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not add these items in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why add them when you want to remove them right after:

```
lineList = theFinalList.Select( line => 
{
    if (line.PartDescription != "")
        return line.PartDescription + " " + line.PartNumber + "\n";
    else
        return "N/A " + line.PartNumber + "\n";
})
.Where(x => !(x.Contains("FID") || x.Contains("EXCLUDE")))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code sample iterates through the lineList and removes lines that contain FID or EXCLUDE.

```
for(int i = lineList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (lineList[i].Contains("FID") || lineList[i].Contains("EXCLUDE"))
       lineList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

It is important to traverse a list in reverse order when deleting items.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the items in your `theFinalList` list while you are iterating over `theFinalList` in a `foreach` loop. In this case, you may get `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message *“Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.”*

you have to do something like this:

```
List<string> removals = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in theFinalList)
{
    //do stuff with (s);
    removals.Add(s);
}

foreach (string s in removals)
{
    theFinalList.Remove(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
foreach (var line in theFinalList)
{
    string T = "";
    if (line.PartDescription != "")
        T = line.PartDescription + " " + line.PartNumber + "\n";
    else
        T = "N/A " + line.PartNumber + "\n";

    if (!(T.Contains("FID") || T.Contains("EXCLUDE"))
        lineList.Add (T);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var excludingTexts = new [] { "FID", "EXCLUDE" }
lineList = lineList.Where(y => !excludingTexts.Any(x => line.PartDescription.Contains(x) || line.PartNumber.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

Or you can rewrite it as:

```
var excludingTexts = new [] { "FID", "EXCLUDE" }
List<string> lineList = (from line in theFinalList
                         where !excludingTexts.Any(x => line.PartDescription.Contains(x) || line.PartNumber.Contains(x))
                         select line.PartDescription != "" ? 
                                line.PartDescription + " " + line.PartNumber + "\n" : 
                                "N/A " + line.PartNumber + "\n"
                         ).ToList();
```

Comment: Only line.Contains(x) won't work (line is not a string), and we should be  using line.PartDescription.Contains and line.PartNumber.Contains at that point, ternary operator with duplicated logic also not very readable I think

Comment: Updated the solution to use `PartDescription`and `PartNumber` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think its more logical approach

```
Regex exclude = new Regex("FID|EXCLUDE");
foreach (var line in theFinalList.Where(
 ln => !exclude.Match(ln.PartDescription).Success && 
       !exclude.Match(ln.PartNumber ).Success))){

    string partDescription = "N/A";
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.PartDescription)){
        partDescription = line.PartDescription;
    }
    lineList.Add(partDescription  + " " + line.PartNumber + "\n");
}
```

edit regex for your needs (ignore case maybe or multiline, probably compiled too) and feel free to replace `"\n"` with `Environment.NewLine`